# Problems compiling memcached_functions_mysql

Tags: memcached

I am trying to compile package memcached_functions_mysql-1.1.tag.gz I downloaded and installed libmemcached in /usr/lib/ on running 
./configure --with-mysql=/home/y/bin/mysql_config --libdir=/home/y/lib/mysql/ --with-libmemcached=/usr/lib/memcached.so.2.0.0

in the memcached_functions_mysql directory I get error: message checking for libmemcached >= 0.17... configure: error: libmemcached not found

I have tried using both --with-libmemcached and also by changing /etc/ld.so.conf to include the library path where libmemcached is.

But still I am not able to compile.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and finally figured it out.

With libmemcached installed here:

```
/usr/local/lib/libmemcached.so
```

The config parameter needed to be:

```
--with-libmemcached=/usr/local/
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to compile by giving correct value to the variable `--with-libmemcached`.